# Linux : Data extraction from text file

Tags: command-line, gnome, grep, sed, awk

I have a text file in which thousands of data is there. eg.

```
id=row_value
profile=row_value
name=row_value
email=row_value
address=row_value

id=row_value2
profile=row_value2
name=row_value2
email=row_value2
address=row_value2

.       .       .
.       .       .
.       .       .
```

I want to Extract all `name` and `email` from that file. eg.

```
name=row_value
email=row_value

name=row_value2
email=row_value2

.       .       .
.       .       .
.       .       .
```

NOTE : Note the new line after each `name` and `email` pairs ..

I Know it will be done in some linux commands like `grep`, `sed`, `awk` etc ..
I'm Noob in linux commands and please help me regarding this ..

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086628/how-to-extract-text-which-matches-particular-fields-in-text-file-using-linux-com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
grep "name\|email" <Path to your File>
```

Comment: great ... but how to append a new blank line after `name=row_value2
email=row_value2` .. thanx for ur help

Comment: `grep '^name\|^email\|^$' file` will preserve the empty lines as well

Comment: it is not working .. @steeldriver

Comment: @user3710243 is your file **exactly** as shown in your original post?

Comment: ... what I mean is, if the "blank" lines actually contain whitespace, you will need to change the last group from `^$` to something like `^\s*$`

Answer (score 0):

To keep the conscience clean, here's an `awk` version:

```
$ awk '$0~/name/||/email/ {if ($0~/email/) $3="\n"; print $0}' testerfile.txt 
name=row_value
email=row_value  

name=row_value2
email=row_value2
```

And this one, will append the dots:

`awk '$0~/name/||/email/ {if ($0~/email/) $3="\n"; print $0}; $0~/^.[[:blank:]].[[:blank:]]./ {print} ' testerfile.txt`

Output:

```
$awk '$0~/name/||/email/ {if ($0~/email/) $3="\n"; print $0}; $0~/^.[[:blank:]].[[:blank:]]./ {print} ' testerfile.txt 
name=row_value
email=row_value  

name=row_value2
email=row_value2  

.       .       .
.       .       .
.       .       .
```

A much simpler version of the first version:

`awk '/^name/; /^email/ {$3="\n"; print}' testerfile.txt`

Anchored regex will prevent for finding words "name" and "email" elsewhere in the text, and only in the beginning of a line